# Coq : replace hypothesis into implication

Tags: coq

I am learning Coq and I encountered an issue : how can I switch from that context

```
HA : A
HABC : A -> B -> C
```

to this one ?

```
HA : B -> C
```

I tried apply and rewrite tactics but it did not work.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `HABC` to `HA` to yield a witness of `B -> C`, which, by the way, it would make more sense to name `HBC` than `HA`, already used. Using ssreflect, you could write:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma foo A B C (HA : A) (HABC : A -> B -> C) : false.
Proof.
have HBC := HABC HA.
```

If you want to keep the `HA` name, one way to do it would be to replace the `have` with

```
have {HA} HA := HABC HA.
```

where the `{HA}` clears `HA` from the environment so that you can reuse the `HA` name right way for the result of the application.

Comment: In "vanilla Coq", you may write `specialize (HABC HA) as HBC.`.  Clearing `HABC` with `clear` is optional.

Comment: In recent versions, the pattern `{HA} HA` will lead to a "Duplicate clear" warning. It is enough to write `{}HA`: this replaces the previous definition of `HA` by the new one.